# send dataSchema to mongodb using postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I update the question with more information: "
i'm pretty new to Express/mongodb , i'm trying to send my userSchema to mongoDb using postman but i get this error: "

[image: postman]

[image: postman]
 this is my main script :

```
mongoose
  .connect(config.mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log("db connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post("/api/users/register", (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);
  user.save((err, userData) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });
  });
  return res.status(200);
});
app.listen(5000);
```

this is the userSchema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: 1
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  role: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  token: {
    type: String
  },
  tokenExp: {
    type: Number
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = { User };
```

please what am i making wrong ?

Comment: Firstly change GET method to the POST in the postman. Secondly in body, be sure you send JSON. Thirdly put `return res.status(200);` line after the if (err) line

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the 'body' tab in Postman? I suspect there's an error in your JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a POST request but you are using a GET request in postman so change it better to use async and await because responding from the server may take some time, so try this

```
app.post('/api/users/register', async (req, res) => {
const user = new User({

   //This comes from your schema 
   //I assumed you only have one schema named name
    name: req.body.name,

});
   try{
   const savedPost = await user.save();
   res.json(savedPost);
  } catch(err) {
   res.json({message: err})
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You create your function in POST method but in Postman you are using the GET method. Please choose the POST method and try to send Raw data inside the Body in Postman.

Please use the following code for allowing body-parser JSON and Methods.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*' }));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  next();
});
```